# Best open source library or application to crawl and data mine web sites

Tags: web-crawler, data-mining, extract, text-extraction

I would like to know what is the best eopen-source library for crawling and analyzing websites. One example would be a crawler property agencies, where I would like to grab information from a number of sites and aggregate them into my own site. For this I need to crawl the sites and extract the property ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do a lot of scraping, using excellent python packages [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml), [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

I also suggest to look at [lxml](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/) and [Scrapy](http://dev.scrapy.org/), though I don't use them currently (still planning to try out scrapy).

Perl language also has great facilities for scraping.

Comment: Perl is fantastic, you can write a crawler in very few lines using UserAgent::somethingorother. How you analyze the html/javascript, that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

PHP/cURL is a very powerful combination, especially if you want to use the results directly in a web page...

Answer (score 1):

In common with Mr Morozov I do quite a bit of scraping too, principally of job sites. I've never had to resort to mechanize, if that helps any. Beautifulsoup in combination with urllib2 have always been sufficient.

I have used lxml, which is great. However, I believe it may not have been available with Google apps a few months ago when I tried it, if you need that.

My thanks are due to Mr Morozov for mentioning Scrapy. Hadn't heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Scrapy, you should also look at [Parselets](http://parselets.com/)